# Veutify multiselect - get the selected items as JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I've populated JSON  object into `v-select` and it working fine but I need to get selected items as JSON object, currently I'm getting as array but I need it as JSON object.

```
 <v-select
      v-model="timeBandValues"
      :items="timeBandOptions"
      item-text="timeBandId"
      item-value="timeBandId"
      label="Select"
      multiple
      chips
      hint="What are the target regions"
      persistent-hint
    ></v-select>
```

I populated this axios json object(assumed that I have selected two items 1,2 out of three)

```
    timeBandOptions = [
        {
            "timeBandId": 1,
            "start": "14:30:00",
            "end": "22:00:00",
            
        },
        {
            "timeBandId": 2,
            "start": "15:30:00",
            "end": "23:00:00",
           
        },
        {
            "timeBandId": 3,
            "start": "16:00:00",
            "end": "21:00:00",
            
        }
    ]
```

> I have array to store selected items

```
timeBandsValues[]
```

> Actual output

```
timeBandsValues[1,2]
```

> Expected output

```
timeBandsValues[
        {
            "timeBandId": 1,
           
            
        },
        {
            "timeBandId": 2,
           
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return-object` prop to your select in order to return the whole object :

```
  <v-select
    v-model="timeBandValues" :items="items" item-text="timeBandId"
     item-value="timeBandId" label="Select" 
     return-object
     multiple chips hint="What are the target regions" persistent-hint></v-select>
```

Then you could use `map` to return only the desired field like :

```
 timeBandValues.map(val=>val.timeBandId)
```